# Google Apps Script: Simple onEdit() trigger breaking when external document objects are introduced

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

**My question:** Why does the onEdit() trigger in the script below only work when the "OTHER SPREADSHEET" variables are commented-out? The script used to work as written but no longer does until those variables are toggled off.

**Context:**
My script contains:

- A simple onEdit() trigger
- Variables for accessing objects from the current sheet as well as other objects on a separate spreadsheet document

The onEdit() trigger only works when the variables for accessing the objects from the other spreadsheet document are commented-out. The script used to work fine until it began under-performing and then ceasing functionality altogether. I had made no changes to the script before it stopped working. I've provided a condensed and simplified version of the code below, which behaves similarly to the original script.

**My code:**

```
//THIS SPREADSHEET
//Variables for this sheet
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
var mainSheet = ss.getSheetByName('CURRENT_SHEET_NAME');

//FUNCTION
//This function only works if the other sheet variables below are commented-out
function onEdit(e) {
mainSheet.getRange('J15').setValue('it works!');
}

//OTHER SPREADSHEET
//When not commented-out, the onEdit function does not work
var db = SpreadsheetApp.openById('OTHER_SPREADSHEET_ID');
var dbSheet = db.getSheetByName('OTHER_SHEET_NAME');
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason that it doesn't work is no permission to use `openById` under the current situation. You can see the error at View - Execution transcript on script editor. In your script, the variables of `ss, sheet, mainSheet, db and dbSheet` are defined as the global variables. So when `onEdit()` is launched, `SpreadsheetApp.openById()` which is no permission is carried out. By this, the error occurs. When you commented out `SpreadsheetApp.openById()`, the reason that the script works fine is this.

In order to solve this problem, there are 2 patterns.

1. Insert the variables of `db and dbSheet` to a function. By this, when `onEdit()` is launched, `SpreadsheetApp.openById()` is not used.
2. Install `onEdit()` as Installable Triggers. By this, users can use methods that the permission is required. In this case, your script is not required to be modified.

The detail information of Installable Triggers is [here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable).

If I misunderstand your question, I'm sorry.

Comment: Hi @Tanaike, thank you very much. These steps both worked. I very much appreciate your help!

Comment: @W_alarson Welcome. Thank you, too.